# Using ArrayList with JCF Map

Tags: java, variables

I am new using Java collection framework. I have the following piece of code:

```
private Map<String, List<Song>> byArtist() {
    Map<String, List<Song>> byArtist = new HashMap<>();
    for (Song song : mSongs) {
        List<Song> artistSongs = byArtist.get(song.getArtist());
        if (artistSongs == null) {
            artistSongs = new ArrayList<>();
            byArtist.put(song.getArtist(), artistSongs);
       }
       artistSongs.add(song);
    }
    return byArtist;
}
```

The code works fine but, the part where I don't understand is how is the Map `byArtist` is being updated if we are only adding the artist and the song using the put method in the `if` condition, and if we are creating a new instance of the `artistSongs` variable. How and where are the other instances stored?

Comment: All of the list instances are stored in the map that the method creates. What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: You are going over a list of songs (msongs).
If the artist doesn't exist in the current map(byArtist) it will create a new list of songs and put the pair into the byArtist Map.

otherwise it will just put the song into the currently existing list of songs(which is in the map by reference)

Comment: @Mick - Makes sense after combining your comment and Berlyey's comment. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Each song has an artist, you are iterating over songs and also adding songs to artist names, so you can not only find artists for a given song but also find songs by a given artist. More importantly your

```
Map<String, List<Song>> byArtist = new HashMap<>();
```

should be changed to

```
Map<String, List<Song>> byArtist = new HashMap<String, List<Song>>();
```